# Is there any Layout System for arranging the components in Java Micro Edition(J2ME) like Android?

Tags: java, java-me

I am new in J2ME. Previously i was worked with Android now i am switched to J2ME. And i want to know way to arrange the components in J2ME such as Horizontally, Vertically or Relative to another Component.

Also can we set the background image/color on it ?

Awaiting for any reply.